# convert event based data to timeseris data python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series, data-science

This is more of a Data Science Question rather than a python programming problem.

What I have is a event based data and I would like to convert it to a time series data, lets say sampling at every 1ms (milli second)

Please find below a sanpshot for same :-

```
                                          TimeStamps
                                              |
        <...>-957   (-----) [000] ...1   122.100642: clk_set_rate: bimc_msmbus_a_clk 767819776
        <...>-957   (-----) [000] ...1   122.100644: clk_set_rate: bimc_a_clk 767819776
        <...>-957   (-----) [000] ...1   122.100802: clk_set_rate: bimc_msmbus_a_clk 1016856576
cfinteractive-432   (  432) [003] ...1   122.120910: clk_set_rate: pwrcl_clk 633600000
cfinteractive-432   (  432) [003] ...1   122.121172: clk_set_rate: bimc_msmbus_a_clk 199753728
cfinteractive-432   (  432) [003] ...1   122.121177: clk_set_rate: bimc_a_clk 199753728
cfinteractive-432   (  432) [003] ...1   122.121359: clk_set_rate: bimc_msmbus_a_clk 767819776
```

What I want here is to create a time series data our of this event based data at every 1ms, the total duration of data is 30 sec.

What I can think of now is based on the occurence timestamp, put them into corresponding interval.

The problem comes in iterating in a for loop for 30,000 samples and that too as much as number of different clients (ex :- bimc_msmbus_a_clk, pwrcl_clk) etc.

Is there a better way to do this overall and in python.

any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at [resampling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#resampling) in the documentation?